# Getting Error message from linq to entity query.

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

I keep receiving the error
"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String get_Item(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression"
on the following line in my code

var Reviewer = repository.reviewers.FirstOrDefault(t => t.ReviewerName == formCollection[3]);

formCollection[3] is a string returned from a drop down I have contained within a form. The query seems to work O.K. until it returns the value from the database. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I was trying to do too much at once, when I finally thought about it and put formCollection[3] into a string variable and then used the string variable in the linq query everything worked out ok.